# When I run this app with Flutter, I get this error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am very new to Flutter. I found this Android application made with Flutter and tried to run it, but it didn't run and it gave this error. I ran Flutter doctor and no problem was found.

error image

[image: 1]

error :

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fl_chart-0.40.2/lib/src/chart/pie_chart/pie_chart.dart:42:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.

- 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
  package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  ^

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/platform-3.0.2/lib/src/interface/local_platform.dart:46:19: Error: Member not found: 'packageRoot'.
io.Platform.packageRoot; // ignore: deprecated_member_use

Failed to compile application.

app : https://github.com/desi-programmer/money_manager

Video related to this app : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOWy5-zTeWk

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

**flutter pub cache clean**

and then

**flutter pub get**

Comment: unfortunately didn't work

Answer (score 0):

First you have to update the dependencies.
Run these commands:

```
 flutter pub outdated
 flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

Don't forget to change the `pubspec.yaml` to match your SDK version, if you're on Flutter 3.0.4, change your SDK constraints to this

```
 environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.1 <3.0.0"
```

Then run `flutter clean` and finally `flutter pub get`.

Goodluck.